# Why is this javascript function failing to screen out NaN values?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

This is a javascript I use to sum up totals from a column. When a cell is empty or Non Numeric, NaN is returned as the value for sum. Line 6 is supposed to screen for that and set and non-numeric values for zero but that is not happening. Any ideas?

```
function count() {
    var tds = document.getElementById('countit').getElementsByTagName('div');
    var sum = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < tds.length; i ++) {
        if(tds[i].className == 'countme') {
            sum += isNaN(tds[i].innerHTML) ? 0 : parseInt(tds[i].innerHTML);
        }
    }

    document.getElementById('total').innerHTML =sum;
```

Here is an example:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<table id="countit">
<tr>
    <td>Some value</td>
    <td class="count-me"></td>

</tr>
<tr>

<td>Some value</td>
 <td class="count-me">2</td>
</tr>
<tr>

<td>Some value</td>
<td class="count-me">17</td>
</tr>
</table>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var tds = document.getElementById('countit').getElementsByTagName('td');
var sum = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < tds.length; i ++) {
if(tds[i].className == 'count-me') {
sum += isNaN(tds[i].innerHTML) ? 0 : parseInt(tds[i].innerHTML);
}
}
document.getElementById('countit').innerHTML += '<tr><td>total1</td><td>' + sum + '</td></tr>';
</script>
</body>
</html>
}
```

The script is inline, and the first cell is empty. It returns NaN.

Comment: Can you please give us some sample input that recreates the behavior you are seeing?

Comment: shouldn't use `parseInt` without `radix` argument

Comment: `innerHTML` will never return `NaN`, it's always a string. You have to try to parse it first, and that will return `NaN` if it's not a numeric string.

Comment: @Barmar `isNaN("string") === true`

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll("#countit div.countme")` should return the divs you want by the way

Comment: @charlietfl There is an example in the question now. Also happens when you call as a function.

Comment: check the updated answer...with jsfiddle link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24724257/why-is-this-javascript-function-failing-to-screen-out-nan-values/24724330#24724330

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to parse the contents to see if you get `NaN`, because `isNaN("")` is false.

```
for(var i = 0; i < tds.length; i ++) {
    if(tds[i].className == 'countme') {
        var val = parseInt(tds[i].innerHTML, 10);
        if (!isNaN(val)) {
            sum += val;
        }
    }
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/Grq94/2/)

Another demo using the table you added in your question is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/Grq94/3/)

Comment: 10th of April will return 10 if you do it like that

Comment: That also returns zero, no matter the value. Thanks though.

Answer (score 2):

Note that `isNaN` can behave in unintuitive ways. For example: `isNaN('')` evaluates to `false`, and `parseInt('')` evaluates to `NaN`.

EDIT:

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#A_stricter_parse_function) shows an example of stricter way to parse integers, ensuring that only strings consisting of decimal digits (or the string Infinity) are parsed as integers. This prevents the string "50 ways to leave your lover" from being parsed as `50`, as `parseInt` will do. This will need to be modified to allow for floating point numbers, and strings will need leading/trailing whitespace trimmed before this function is used:

```
filterInt = function (value) {
  if(/^(\-|\+)?([0-9]+|Infinity)$/.test(value))
    return Number(value);
  return NaN;
}

console.log(filterInt('421'));               // 421
console.log(filterInt('-421'));              // -421
console.log(filterInt('+421'));              // 421
console.log(filterInt('Infinity'));          // Infinity
console.log(filterInt('421e+0'));            // NaN
console.log(filterInt('421hop'));            // NaN
console.log(filterInt('hop1.61803398875'));  // NaN
console.log(filterInt('1.61803398875'));     // NaN
```

Comment: 421e+0 is a valid int as far as I know. If you agree, you can just return Number(value) instead of passing it through a regex - http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/FYPm7/

Comment: The code above _strictly_ parses decimal integer literals, if those are defined to strictly be a string of decimal digits. I know there is no distinction in Javascript between integers and floats (both are `Number`s), but many languages (e.g. Java) consider `421e+0` to be a floating point/double precision literal. I think the OP really should think about what he wants to allow in those `<td>`s, why isn't he or she using `parseFloat`?

Comment: If you allow Infinity, you aught to allow 421e+0

Answer (score 1):

Your `isNaN` check is fine for non-numeric values but doesn't work for empty strings:

```
> isNaN("")
false
> parseInt("")
NaN
```

You could use [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) like this:

```
var s = Number(tds[i].innerHTML);
if (!isNaN(s)) sum += s;
```

`Number` will perform a type conversion on the input and return a `NaN` if it cannot be parsed as a number.

Answer (score 0):

try replacing:

```
 sum += isNaN(tds[i].innerHTML) ? 0 : parseInt(tds[i].innerHTML);
```

with, 
EDIT:

```
if(tds[i].innerHTML){   
 if(isNaN(''+tds[i].innerHTML))
     sum+=0; 
 else
     sum+=parseInt(tds[i].innerHTML);
}
```

because isNaN(null) also returns false.

Jsfiddle updated:

http://jsfiddle.net/Grq94/4/

I think it will suffice.

Comment: No that breaks it all together. I just get a persistent return of zero.

Answer (score 0):

Depending if you expect zeros before in the left. This validation will work

```
var myVar = '';
var myVar2 = '312';

if (myVar == parseInt(myVar)) {
    // False! Stop there.
}

if (myVar2 == parseInt(myVar2)) {
    // True! Go on
}
```